# How to integrate foreign servers/tables in rspec tests for a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I'm having trouble trying to test some models for foreign tables in my Rails application. I'm not sure what is the best approach to include this models in my tests.

I created a foreign server and table in a migration like this:

```
def up
  execute %{
CREATE SERVER myserver FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 'foo', dbname 'foodb', port '5432');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE users (name character varying(255)) SERVER myserver;
  }%
end
```

The problem is that my testing environment uses exactly the same table (not a testing table), because the structure file has the development foreign server definition and as rspec loads structure file, it creates a foreign table in my test database that points to the original table in my foreign server. How can I create a foreign server/tables for testing to be loaded when I run my rspec tests?

Thanks in advance!